# Calculating millions of distances with Road Graph

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, distance

I'm new to GIS but thanks to the answers I got in another question here on `GIS stack exchange` I was able to increase my knowledge significantly. This question is related to an earlier question I asked and got answer, but since this is a new question, I thought better to ask a new question instead of continuing on the older one.

I have about 160,000 addresses (points) and a (vector format) map of roads and 10 city limits (polygon). I want to:

- Calculate the distance from each of these addresses to the city borders (or possible the city centers - a point - if that is easier).
- That is, for each city I want 10 distances. I don't just want the possibility to do it one by one - I want the total 1,600,000 distances once and for all!

I was earlier advised to use either `Road Graph` for `QGIS` og `pgRouting` for `PostGIS`.
I have stated using `Road Graph`. I was able to import all the data into `QGIS`, install the `Road Graph` plugin, and calculate the distance between to points. My question now is:

- How do I get `Road Graph` to calculate all the 1,600,000 distances? And can it at all be done with 'Road Graph'?

Thanks

Comment: distance as in a 'straight line' distance?

Comment: No, as in shortest path on roads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have understood Road Graph, it is very limited in its functionality. Only A-B routing on screen. No automation of processing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Do you have another suggestion? Do you know if `pgrouting` can do this?

Comment: I would primarily suggest my own offerings from www.routeware.dk, but I guess pgrouting can also do it.

Comment: Thanks - looking for a free solution though.

Comment: @Mace How big is your road graph (how many edges)? PgRouting should certainly be able to cope with 1-2 million routes without much fuss.

Comment: @underdark I have three levels of roads varying in size (freeway, interstate, and small road). I don't know exactly how many roads each one has. Preferably, I want to use all three types of roads, and then penalize using the small roads and the interstates, is this possible in `pgrouting`? I think `pgrouting` is the way to go for me no matter what, so I will try to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar once upon a time, before pgrouting was mature.  I wrote a simple PHP script that would query for the road graph and perform a Dijkstra search (PHP made for an easy "query container").  In my case, this worked because my graph was small.  I also made things easier by eliminating nodes that didn't actually branch.  Eg, if A->B->C, I just combined A, B, and C into one geometry.

TL;DR You're going to have to write a bit of software.  Dijkstra implementations can be found easily, but you need to feed data into them yourself.  If your graph is large, you're going to need to find a way to simplify.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think I will look at pgRouting before starting to code myself. It already includes a Djikstra search as far as I know.